# Query to Search using Solr Parent and Child Relationship

Tags: postgresql, solr

I use solr **8.7** version.

This is my child tables.**id** column is refered parent table.

```
        "aliasName":"Ayyad Nazmi Salih Khalil ",
        "id":"1",
        "quality":"Good",
        "_version_":1692002830831845376},
      
        "aliasName":"Eyad Nazmi Saleh Khalil",
        "id":"1",
        "quality":"Good",
        "_version_":1692002830831845376},
```

This is my Parent table.

```
{
        "secondName":"NAZMI ",
        "listedOn":"2017-02-22",
        "refNo":"QDi.400",
        "firstName":"IYAD",
        "nationality":"Jordan",
        "id":"1",
        "fourthName":" KHALIL",
        "listType":"Al-Qaida",
        "unlistType":"UN List",
        "_version_":1692002830831845376},
      {
```

I want to search Child table under **listtype**.I try to use the block query parser.it not sucessfull.
I hope to guidence to solve this issue.